# Sharing config file between puphpet and puppet

Tags: puppet, puphpet

Is it possible to share a config file between puphpet and puppet?

The scenario is;
our development team is using vagrant and puphpet in dev.environments. Once they are ready with a release, I would like to have a clone of their setup (php modules etc) and apply this using puppet on our production servers...

The ideal way would be to simply apply the config.yaml file directly in puppet, but I'm not sure if they "speak the same language"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible. PuPHPet uses its own baked-in Puppet, and the code for that is [here](https://github.com/puphpet/puphpet/tree/master/archive/puphpet/puppet).

What you could do, of course, is write your own wrapper around PuPHPet that hooks into the bits there that you want to build a PuPHPet-like production environment, minus Vagrant. It wouldn't be too hard.